# (ts2339) Property 'token' does not exists on type 'TopicMessage' in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Below is my custom interface with firebase admin message interface

```
interface PushPayload {
  userId: number
  conId?: number
  pushLogCodeKey: string
  messagePayload: admin.messaging.Message
}
```

And I tried to get token

```
const blah = something.messagePayload.token
```

But I got an error code ts(2339). In firebase admin module, there are some single pipe line in assign statement. Is there any connection between my problem and them?

Below is interface type.

```
interface TokenMessage extends BaseMessage {
  token: string;
}

interface TopicMessage extends BaseMessage {
  topic: string;
}

interface ConditionMessage extends BaseMessage {
  condition: string;
}

export namespace admin.messaging {
  type Message = TokenMessage | TopicMessage | ConditionMessage;
  ...
}
```

My typescript version is 3.9.7 and firebase-admin version is 9.2.0

I'm sorry to make you read my terrible English.

Comment: The type of Message can be anything: TokenMessage, TopicMessage or ConditionMessage. `token` only exist in TokenMessage. So it doesn't guarantee that the type of Message will be TokenMessage. That's why you're seeing this error. Try removing TopicMessage and Condition message. Hopefully you won't see the error.

Comment: @ApalShah
Is there any way to avoid this error such as add something after "messagePayload: admin.messaging.Message"? I'm afraid that I don't know what will happen because of library change..

Comment: Writing a custom type guard will help TypeScript narrow the type and remove the error, and also give you a path to follow if your required property doesn't exist. See this bit of the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code declares that type `Message` can be **any** one of the types `TokenMessage`, `TopicMessage`, or `ConditionMessage`.

```
type Message = TokenMessage | TopicMessage | ConditionMessage;
```

It is using a TypeScript [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html), which I suggest reading about.

Since `Message` can be any one of those types, it is not guaranteed to have a `token` property.  Only `TokenMessage` is guaranteed to have a `token` property.  If you want to assume that the message is always a `TokenMessage`, then you should check to see if the property exists (or cast the type) before using it:

```
const payload = something.messagePayload
if (payload.token) {
    const token = payload.token
}
```